# IoTデバイスにCSVデータを格納後、別ファイルに変換したい

Tags: python, csv

IoTデバイスへ以下のようなCSVデータを格納し、

```
'datetime', 'people', 'week', 'temperature', 'weather', 'precipitation', 'snowfall', 'snowcover', 'wind', 'humidity', 'holiday', 'vacation', 'event', 'eventtime', 'holidays', 'covid'
'2021/09/02 18:56:00', '36', '木', '23.8', '曇', '0', '0', '0', '3.3', '80', 'なし', 'なし', 'なし', 'なし', '0', '1'
'2021/09/02 18:57:00', '33', '木', '23.8', '曇', '0', '0', '0', '3.3', '80', 'なし', 'なし', 'なし', 'なし', '0', '1'
'2021/09/02 18:58:00', '33', '木', '23.8', '曇', '0', '0', '0', '3.3', '80', 'なし', 'なし', 'なし', 'なし', '0', '1'
```

txtファイルへ書き出しをしたいと考えています。

以下のpythonコードを作成しています。

```
# test.py

import csv
import sys
from pathlib import Path
home_path = str(Path.home())
print (open((home_path + '/Desktop/text書き出し.txt'), 'a'))

filename = '20210902.csv'
with open(filename, encoding='cp932', newline='') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvreader:
        print(row)

a_text = ""
for a in ():
    a_text += a
    a_text += "\n\n"

desktop = str(Path.home()) + "\Desktop"
a_file = open(Path(desktop +"text書き出し.txt"),"w")
a_file.writelines(a_text.rstrip())
a_file.close()
```

上記を実行すると、ターミナルにCSVデータの中身が出力され、
ファイルがない場合は作成はされますが、
中身は空の状態になってしまいます。
また、同名のtxtファイルがある場合はターミナル上にCSVデータの
中身が出力されるのみです。

どのように書き換えたら、txtファイルへCSVファイルの中身を
出力できますでしょうか。

Comment: どのような内容書き出す予定ですか？ CSVと全く同じ内容？

Comment: @oriri  様
基本的にはCSVと同内容を書き出したいと考えています。実測値を以て未来日の人数予測をしたいと考えており、その前哨段階です。(出力ファイルは、txt予定としていますがtxtでなくても問題ありません。)
※センサーデータ等を使用することが難しく、①オープンデータを利用しIoTデバイスへ読み込ませ、②データファイルを作成し、③そのデータを可視化ツールへ送信する、という挙動をさせたい次第です。。。

Comment: 例外処理を意識すると良いと思います。 https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/1911/05/news020.html

Comment: 質問のコードでは `a_text` を**文字列**として扱ってるのかなとも思え, しかし [writelines](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) 使ってるので **リスト** として扱おうとしてるようにも見えます。何を行いたいか説明がないと伝わらないかも

Comment: もしも解決したのなら [こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)を。そうでないのならコメントか質問文かで詳細記してください

Answer (score 0, accepted):

全く同じ内容(を出力したい) ということであれば以下のようにできます

```py
import io
csvfile = '''
'datetime', 'people', 'week', 'temperature', 'weather', 'precipitation', 'snowfall', 'snowcover', 'wind', 'humidity', 'holiday', 'vacation', 'event', 'eventtime', 'holidays', 'covid'
'2021/09/02 18:56:00', '36', '木', '23.8', '曇', '0', '0', '0', '3.3', '80', 'なし', 'なし', 'なし', 'なし', '0', '1'
'2021/09/02 18:57:00', '33', '木', '23.8', '曇', '0', '0', '0', '3.3', '80', 'なし', 'なし', 'なし', 'なし', '0', '1'
'2021/09/02 18:58:00', '33', '木', '23.8', '曇', '0', '0', '0', '3.3', '80', 'なし', 'なし', 'なし', 'なし', '0', '1'
'''

import csv
import sys
from pathlib import Path

with io.StringIO(csvfile.strip()) as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvreader:
        print(row)

    desktop = Path.home() / "Desktop"
    with open(desktop / "text書き出し.txt", "w") as a_file:
        f.seek(0)
        for ln in f:
            a_file.write(ln)
```

---

##### (update)

`a_text`へ str型として蓄え, 出力するなら

```py
with open( 〜 ) as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvreader:
        print(row)

    f.seek(0)
    a_text = f.read()

desktop = Path.home() / "Desktop"
with open(desktop / "text書き出し.txt", "w") as a_file:
    a_file.write(a_text)
```

行のリストとして ([`writelines()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) で) 扱いたいのであれば, それを読み込む際に [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) を使用するかもしくは**データを加工**する必要がある

(`write` に対するのは `read` であり, `writelines` に対するのは `readlines`)